# How can you view source and keep Vim commands enabled in Vimium?

Tags: google-chrome, vim, keyboard-shortcuts

When I view source using [Vimium](http://vimium.github.io/), it disables the Vim commands.
Ideally would like to keep the commands active so that I can search the source code using regex and avoid having to switch back to the mouse to close the tab or revert back to chrome commands.

Does anyone know how I can enable the Vim(ium) commands whilst viewing source?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues/30

Answer (score 0):

I use vimium myself, so I was interested in this too.

```
chrome://flags
```

Look for "Extensions on chrome:// URLs", enable it.  Then click on 'Relaunch Chrome' to apply the change.

This only allows an extension to be used in chrome:// URLs **IF** the extension requests this permission.

But it's a step in the right direction.  I'm not sure if Vimium or Vrome (two nice vim keystroke extensions) ask for this permission.  Haven't tried this yet.

And if you changed anything ELSE while you were poking around in the flags... Well, be careful!

EDIT:  Tried it with Vrome, still doesn't work.  Evidently no one is asking for this permission.

And Chrome complains about the Extensions in Chrome:// URL's being enabled.  Bummer.